# Google Analytics Tracking Event Not Working

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I've added a tracking event using jQuery onclick using Google analytics.js but it doesn't work at all.. Everything I fire the event I get undefined in response.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-36828246-2', 'curiousworkout.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#generate_header').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ga('generate_workout', 'header_click');
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});

$('#generate_top_list').click(function(){
    ga('generate_workout', 'top_list_click');
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});

$('#generate_top_main').click(function(){
    ga('generate_workout', 'top_main_click');
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your event submission lines are missing a lot of data, most notably the command to `send` the `event`.

From [the Universal Analytics event tracking guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events):

> To send an event, you pass the ga function the `send` command with the `event` hit type
>
> ```
> ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4);
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> - `button` is the category
> - `click` is the action
> - `nav buttons` is the label
> - `4` is the value

From your code, I will assume "generate_workout" is the category of event action you are trying to track and "top_main_click" is the action, and that you don't need a value prescribed to the event.

This gives us something like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'generate_workout', 'top_main_click');
```

If relevant, I would consider adding the *label* attribute as the URL of the page where the action was generated so you can also track where events come from.

Answer (score 0):

In order to track a custom event you should call the ga function with a send command. Read further on the Google analytics devguides [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). According to tracking custom event guide the above code should be:

```
ga('send','event','generate_workout','header_click');
```